# Substring of a column in a join condition of database view

Tags: abap, opensql, database-view

I need to create an SAP Database view for EKPO table with some other tables. And need to get EBELN column's first three chars like Substring(EBELN,0,3)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is impossible.

Even in CDS views, according to rules for ON operands, user-defined and standard function calls are [prohibited](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abencds_cond_expr_on_join.htm):

> No path expressions or other expressions or function calls can be specified.